# Ignore or remove object with null in reduce

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following in my js code:

```
// Format the links 
const newLinks = Object.keys(this.props.mission.links).reduce((array, key) => {
  return [...array, {url: this.props.mission.links[key], name:key}]
}, []);
```

which creates my object like so:

```
{ url: "https://i.imgur.com/03gonKW.png", name: "mission_patch" }
```

but there are cases where the url is null how can I ignore that so it's not created in the object meaning if the url is null it should skip it.

Comment: Maybe this `return this.props.mission.links[key] ?
   [...array, {url: this.props.mission.links[key], name:key}] : array;`

Comment: how about ` return [...array, {url: this.props.mission.links[key] !== undefined ? this.props.mission.links[key] : ""  , name:key}] ` ?

Comment: exactly, use a `ternary op` OR `if()` to judge the `url`

Comment: Thanks @Hassan Imam that worked

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to add a condition in your reducer:

```
const newLinks = Object.keys(this.props.mission.links).reduce((array, key) => {
  if(!this.props.mission.links[key]) {
    return array;
  }
  return [...array, {url: this.props.mission.links[key], name:key}]
}, []);
```

But, note that this case (in general) matches map better then reduce:

```
const links = this.props.mission.links;
const newLinks = Object.keys(links)
  .filter(key => !!links[key])
  .map(key => ({url: links[key], name: key}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to do the following

```
return this.props.mission.links[key] ? [...array, {url: this.props.mission.links[key], name:key}] : array;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply filter first to get only keys with not null values:

`let filteredKeys = Object.keys(this.props.mission.links).filter((key) => !!this.props.mission.links[key])`
And then apply your reduce, you can also chain these operations:
`let result = Object.keys(this.props.mission.links).filter((key) => !!this.props.mission.links[key]).reduce((array, key) => { return [...array, {url: this.props.mission.links[key], name:key}] }, [])`